# ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to android.net.wifi.WifiManager

Tags: android

Super strange issue.

I get the following Exception:

```
ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to android.net.wifi.WifiManager
```

in this line:

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
```

it is very rare - happened once on an app with thousands of daily users. 
It happened on Samsung S5 device (SM-G900F) with Android 6.0.1

How can `getSystemService()` return a String? any ideas beside using context.getApplicationContext?

Comment: Is it happening more than once on the same device? or just really rare to happen ?

Comment: And where are you using this code ? derived context or application context ?

Comment: @YamenNassif It happened twice for the same user - regarding Application Context  - this is exactly what we have thought about and this is the fix we are offering. But still, even with a regular context and not Application context - I would expect a different Exception - not a classCastException to a String, don't you agree? it makes me uncomfortable to say - yep - it is the ApplicationContext issue

Comment: so that means it changed in 27?

Comment: Now i am confused to for this

Comment: I totally agree but as the docs says its a memory leak issue, and it wouldn't surprise me to see such an Exception acutally it wouldn't surprise me to see even more weird ones with memory leaks. A WifiManager for management of Wi-Fi connectivity. On releases before NYC, it should only be obtained from an application context, and not from any other derived context to avoid memory leaks within the calling process. ref : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getSystemService(java.lang.Class<T>)

Comment: @NirajSanghani This device is using 6.0.1 and the target SDK for this project is 22 
So 27 behavior change seems not possible.

Comment: I agree with you. But i do not trust the update that might have been pushed by manufacturer. It would be good to raise the query with freaking Samsung, to stop screwing us.

Answer (score 0):

Use getApplicationContext() instead of context

`WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);`

Comment: This is what we did. however, it is still not explaining this ClassCastExcepiton